# Updating Pivot Tables in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing some code for someone to update a pivot table field based on the contents entered in a particular cell.

I am unfamiliar with VBA and programming for excel but I followed some tutorials and would like if someone here could look over what I've done just to see if everything looks ok before I give it to them as I don't have access to their excel worksheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Application.Range(B8)) _
    Is Nothing Then
        UpdatePivotFieldFromRange _
        B8, B3, Outfield
End If
End Sub


Public Sub UpdatePivotFieldFromRange(RangeName As String, Fieldname As       String, PivotTableName As String)

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Application.Range(RangeName)

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim Sheet As Worksheet

For Each Sheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    Set pt = Sheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName)
Next
If pt Is Nothing Then GoTo Ex
On Error GoTo Ex

pt.ManualUpdate = True
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim Field As PivotField
Set Field = pt.PivotFields(Fieldname)
Field.ClearAllFilters
Field.EnableItemSelection = False
SelectPivotItem Field, rng.Text
pt.RefreshTable

Ex:
pt.ManualUpdate = False
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Public Sub SelectPivotTableItem(Field As PivotField, ItemName As String)
Dim Item As PivotItem
For Each Item In Field.PivotItems
    Item.Visible = (Item.Caption = ItemName)
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I just noticed that you're passing undefined variables into string arguments. That means this code is broken, does nothing, and is off-topic here.

Comment: @RubberDuck Without `Option Explicit`, variables don't need to be declared... OP probably meant `Application.Range("B8")` though. Dermot, please edit the *actual working code* into your post - `Application.Range(B8)` likely only does `Application.Range("")` (which blows up with a runtime error #1004), since `B8` is an identifier, not a string.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant @Mat'sMug. I was just upset that I spent time reviewing broken code.

Answer (score 3):

So, let's start with the Worksheet event and what you're trying to do. You only want to trigger the pivot update if the changed cell is `B8`. There's no need to intersect, just check the target's address.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "B8"
            UpdatePivotFieldFromRange "B8", "B3", Outfield
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that I properly indented the code and got rid of that horrid line continuation.

---

Now, we can move onto `UpdatePivotFieldFromRange`. Kinda...

You're immediately recreating the target range at the beginning of this sub, so just pass `Target` in as a range instead of a string. That changes the event to this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address = "B8"
            UpdatePivotFieldFromRange Target, "B3", Outfield
    End If
End Sub
```

And your declaration of `UpdatePivotFieldFromRange` to this:

```
Public Sub UpdatePivotFieldFromRange(rng As Range, Fieldname As String, PivotTableName As String)
```

But that's still not right. There's no reason for this to be public, declare it private instead. I also don't like the name `rng`. It's not meaningful, but I'll leave it to you to give it a meaningful name.

There is so much wrong here I'm not sure where to start.

> ```
> For Each Sheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Set pt = Sheet.PivotTables(PivotTableName)
> Next
> If pt Is Nothing Then GoTo Ex
> ```

- There's no reason to call `Application`. `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets` works just fine.
- ***But*** you're begging for bugs. If the user clicks on another workbook while this is running, the sub is suddenly working on a different workbook. Use a Workbook typed variable instead.

  ```
  Dim book As Workbook
  Set book = ActiveWorkbook

  For Each sheet In book.Worksheets
  ```
- The next thing to note is you're setting `On Error GoTo Next` at each iteration of the loop. It should be moved outside of the loop.
- ***But***, you shouldn't ***ever*** use `On Error GoTo Next`. Seriously, Never do this. You're telling [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to simply swallow the error. It's analogous to having an empty catch block. Find a way to check to see if the pivot table exists instead.
- Finally, you're using `GoTo` to jump to your error handler. You should also never do this. It's much better to [Raise an Error](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s197/raise-error.htm).

That said, I do like that you're always ensuring that `ScreenUpdating` gets turned back on. (Well, you *would be*, if you set `OnError GoTo Ex` directly upon entering the subroutine.)

---

Again, there's no reason for a private function to be declared `Public`. Look into scoping and declaration in vba. It's important. If these were functions instead of Subs, they would be available as user formulas.

Secondly, do you really intend for this to hide *every* field except the one you're looking for? I doubt it.

> ```
> Public Sub SelectPivotTableItem(Field As PivotField, ItemName As String)
> Dim Item As PivotItem
> For Each Item In Field.PivotItems
>     Item.Visible = (Item.Caption = ItemName)
> Next
> End Sub
> ```

I have a feeling that what you really meant to do was turn the particular field on/off like this.

```
Public Sub SelectPivotTableItem(Field As PivotField, ItemName As String)
    Dim Item As PivotItem
    For Each Item In Field.PivotItems
        If Item.Caption = ItemName Then
            Item.Visible = True
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: *If these were functions instead of Subs, they would be available as user formulas.* - not quite true. This code is written in a spreadsheet's code-behind, which is a class module in disguise. Only public functions written in *code modules* are available as user-defined worksheet functions.

Comment: Good point! So, no in this case, they wouldn't be available as worksheet functions, but it's something to be aware of.

Answer (score 2):

This Private sub is mind boggling with only one cup of coffee this early in the morning...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Application.Range(B8)) _
        Is Nothing Then
            UpdatePivotFieldFromRange _
            B8, B3, Outfield
    End If
End Sub
```

this is after I added the correct indentation to it.

you have a horrible double negative going on here, so let's first change that so it doesn't fry our brains right out of the gate.

if it is nothing, let's just return. if not do the work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Application.Range(B8)) Is Nothing Then
        return  
    End If
    UpdatePivotFieldFromRange B8, B3, Outfield
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Application.Range(B8)) Is Nothing Then
        'Left Empty Intentionally
    Else
        UpdatePivotFieldFromRange B8, B3, Outfield
    End If
End Sub
```

which is probably best written like @RubberDucky said

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Application.Range(B8)) Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If
    UpdatePivotFieldFromRange B8, B3, Outfield
End Sub
```

With an `Exit Sub`

None of that was long enough to warrant a new line operator, especially in the if statement declaration, please don't do that.
I wrote this Sub so that it was easy to follow, you could write it shorter, but it would be confusing again.

---

Indentation is your friend, and in languages without line terminations it is mandatory, luckily for you VB has ending statements, otherwise the lack of indentation would trip you up horribly (like in Python).

Comment: Umm @Malachi, vba doesn't have a `Return` statement... the best we have is an `Exit Sub`.

Comment: well then I will have to shorten that up a bit..... or do nothing, like I wrote?